# Using arrays to generate a players score

Tags: java

I'm trying to use the array method to keep track of scores on my game, I'm having difficulty in doing so when I try to compile and run.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class score
{

    public static void main (String[]args)
    {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int [] arrPlayer = new int[7];

    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[0]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[1]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[2]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[3]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[4]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[5]=scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[6]=scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[0];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[1];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[2];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[3];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[4];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[5];
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: "arrPlayer[6];

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++);

    }

}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? Why is for loop empty?

Answer (score 4):

you missed + to concatenate the array value with the string. And also you didn't close your `System.out.println()` method.

Here is the correction:

```
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[0]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[1]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[2]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[3]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[4]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[5]);
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[6]);
```

And bonus:

You can simplify your code with the following changes making use of loops.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[i] = scan.nextInt();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Java, but you can shorten it with `for` loop:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class score{

    public static void main (String[]args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int [] arrPlayer = new int[7];

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
            arrPlayer[i]=scan.nextInt();
        }

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++) {
            System.out.println("Player " + i + " : Score: " + arrPlayer[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are not concatenating the players score with the text:

```
System.out.println("Player 1 : Score: " + arrPlayer[0]);
```

Also rather than laboriously typing out the same statement, why not do a loop to gather their scores:

```
int [] arrPlayer = new int[7];
for(int i=0; i<arrPlayer.length;i++){
    System.out.println("Please Enter Your Score");
    arrPlayer[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that

```
  for(int i=0; i<7; I++){
      System.out.println("player            score1 :"+arrayplayer[i]);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

for(int i=0; i<7; i++){System.out.println("player score:"+arrayplayer[i]);}